# Youtube embed iframe api playVideo() not working in firefox when the video is on a overlaied block

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to open and play a youtube video in a overlaied block.
The problem is that in Firefox the playVideo() method doesn't seem to work when it is called from the link that also makes the overlay to appear (but it works in Chrome).
Conversely, if I autoplay the video, in Firefox it starts when the overlay appears, while in Chrome it starts when the original page is loaded.
How can I have a solution that works for both the browsers (and possibly a modern IE) ?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  <style>
    .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.6;
        opacity:.60;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 660px;    
        height: 450px;
        margin-left: -330px;
        margin-top: -225px;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }  
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

        <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "showAndPlay();">here</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">
          This is the lightbox content.
          <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';pauseVideo();">Close</a>
          <div id="player"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          //events: {
          //  'onReady': onPlayerReady, // If I uncomment this it works in Firefox but in Chrome the video starts at the page load
          //}
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
      function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }
      function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
      }

      function showAndPlay() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        playVideo();
      }

    </script>  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: curious are you on a Mac? I'm seeing some weirdness on Mac firefox for a similar issue

Comment: @Simon_Weaver sorry, no, I normally use Linux.. I can't 100% remember when I had this issue, but I think I was using Firefox and Chrome on Linux..

Answer (score 0):

Solved moving the youtube client creation in the function called at overlay creation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>   
  <style>
    .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.6;
        opacity:.60;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 660px;    
        height: 450px;
        margin-left: -330px;
        margin-top: -225px;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }  
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

        <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "showAndPlay();">here</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">
          This is the lightbox content.
          <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "stopAndHide();">Close</a>
          <div id="player"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
      function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }
      function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
      }

      function showAndPlay() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        if (!player){
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
          });
        }
        playVideo();
      }

      function stopAndHide(){
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';   
        stopVideo(); 
      }    
    </script>  

  </body>
</html>
```